Cannot load cannot load certificate key PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey failed
Login into GoDaddy account and downloaded the certificates, combined those two certificates using cat command and created a combined.crt certificate. Later I have copied the combined.crt and simplelife.key.txt files in to the ssl location
Also checked the below configuration for sites-available:

sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/simplelife.com.au
##Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
server {
listen 80;
server_name simplelife.com.au www.simplelife.com.au;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
##HTTPS Server Block
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name simplelife.com.au www.simplelife.com.au;
 ssl_certificate /var/www/ssl/combined.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /var/www/ssl/simplelife.key

 ### Other SSL settings

 root /var/www/simplelife.com.au/build;
 index index.html;

 location / {
     try_files $uri /index.html;
 }

 location /service {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 }

}


2 . sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name simplelife.com.au www.simplelife.com.au;
    root /var/www/simplelife.com.au/build;
    index index.html;
}

While running the systemctl status nginx.service in the Vultr server, throws below error, could someone please advise the reason for the error ?
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2024-04-14 12:21:23 UTC; 7min ago
Docs: man:nginx(8)
Process: 8361 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Apr 14 12:21:23 simplelife systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Apr 14 12:21:23 simplelife nginx[8361]: nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate key "/var/www/ssl/628f50dbfca5986c.pem": PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey() failed (SSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY)
Apr 14 12:21:23 simplelife nginx[8361]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
